# Expected a type error

Tags: ios, xcode, protocols

So I created this method:

```
- (void)addToViewController:(SecViewController *)controller 
      didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item;` <br>
```

And `Xcode` keeps giving me `Expected a type` error at **SecViewController ***. What does that mean? **SecViewController** is not a type?

Comment: did you include (aka import) SecViewController.h ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to declare `SecViewController`:

```
@class SecViewController;
```

... at the top of your header.

Note: Don't just `#import` all used headers. This just worsens your header dependencies.